# Nestedscrollview jump up when I scroll horizontal recyclerview into vertical recyclerview

Tags: android

I have this layout structure

HomeActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.minvideo.android.activities.HomeActivity"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    >

   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
   </FrameLayout>

    <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

BottomMenuFragment:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <com.minvideo.android.views.RippleView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_left_control_ripple"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:rv_rippleDuration="200"
                app:rv_color="@color/colorGray"
                app:rv_centered="true"
                app:rv_type="simpleRipple"
                >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_left_control_wrap"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:paddingStart="20dp"
                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_left_control"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/left_control"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </com.minvideo.android.views.RippleView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:text="test"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
                />
            <com.minvideo.android.views.RippleView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_right_control_ripple"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:rv_rippleDuration="200"
                app:rv_color="@color/colorGray"
                app:rv_centered="true"
                app:rv_type="simpleRipple"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_right_control_wrap"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:paddingStart="20dp"
                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_right_control"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"


                 android:contentDescription="@string/right_control"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:visibility="visible"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_likesettings" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </com.minvideo.android.views.RippleView>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.minvideo.android.views.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"          
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

TabFragment(fragment for every tab in tablayout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">


    <com.minvideo.android.views.TabObservableScrollViewWithPaging
        android:id="@+id/rv_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.minvideo.android.views.TabObservableScrollViewWithPaging>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_empty_list_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="@string/clips_empty_list_text"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_timeout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
       >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_timeout_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="@string/check_your_connection"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <com.minvideo.android.views.RippleView
        android:id="@+id/retry_ripple"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tab_timeout_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:rv_rippleDuration="200"
        app:rv_color="@color/colorGray"
        app:rv_centered="true"
        app:rv_type="simpleRipple"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/retry"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_refresh_black_24dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            />

    </com.minvideo.android.views.RippleView>


</RelativeLayout>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tab_server_error_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:text="@string/internal_server_error"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:gravity="center"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tab_no_internet_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:text="@string/no_internet_title"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:gravity="center"
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/save_wrap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:visibility="gone"
    >
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar_save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorGray"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/save_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"

      android:background="@drawable/detail_user_button_follow_23_blue"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save changes"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/root"
 android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
 >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    style="@style/header"
    />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I open activity first time all work good, but when I return to Home Activity from other Activity, recyclerview jump up when I scroll inner horizontal recyclerview. Outer vertical recyclerview and inner horizontal recyclerview:

```
rv.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

If I call

```
universalAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

all works good, but on all horizontal recyclerview change scroll position
Help me fix this bug without  `universalAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Hi!
I've the same problem( Did you find the solution how to fix it?

Comment: <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            >
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

Comment: this work for me

Comment: You should post this comment as answer to this question cause it will help more people to notice it since it's a fix.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got rid of this "jumping in outer view while scrolling inner recylcer view horizontally" issue resolved by introducing one following line.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

As described by the orignal poster in his comment

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   android:orientation="
   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >  
   
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
      android:id="@+id/rv" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" 
      android:focusableInTouchMode="true" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```